# Perl DBI with mysql: how to get return value from a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, perl, stored-procedures, dbi

Does **DBD::mysql** implement the **bind_param_inout** method?
I am getting the following error messages when trying it out:

> DBD::mysql::st bind_param_inout
>   failed: Output parameters not
>   implemented [for Statement "call
>   spCreateTransactionRecord(?, ?)" with
>   ParamValues: 0=Null!, 1=Null!] at
>   ./db.pl line 23

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
use Data::Dumper;

my ($dbh, $dsn, $sth, $sql);
my ($RecID, TypeID);
my ($user, $pass) = '';

# Open DB connection
$dsn = "dbi:mysql:database=mp;mysql_read_default_file=$ENV{HOME}/.my.cnf";
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, 
             {RaiseError=>1, AutoCommit=>0, ShowErrorStatement=>1}) 
            || die "DB open error: $DBI::errstr";

# Call stored procedure
$sql = "call spCreateTransactionRecord(?, ?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bind_param_inout(2, \$p_RecID, 11, {TYPE=>SQL_INTEGER});
$sth->execute($p_TypeID) || print $sth->errstr;

# Disconnects
$dbh->commit();
$dbh->disconnect;
```

The stored procedures is declared as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateTransactionRecord (
    IN  p_TypeID INTEGER,
    OUT p_RecID  INTEGER
)
```

Comment: Environment: Ubuntu 10 with default mysql install (5.1) and perl 5.10.1 with modules freshly installed from CPAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known bug with "Verified" status, meaning it never got addressed.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23554

That bug reports also contains a possible workaround.

A separate confirmation that the issue is still not addressed is that [the source code for the current (4.017) version](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.017/dbdimp.c) still has the error:

```
if (is_inout)
{
   do_error(sth, JW_ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, "Output parameters not implemented", NULL);
   return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. Strange that they haven't fixed this bug yet, considering it's been reported in 2006.

Answer (score 4):

The new code with a workaround:

```
# Call stored procedure
$sql = "call spCreateTransactionRecord($p_TypeID, \@rtnVal)";
$dbh->do($sql);
$p_RecID = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT @rtnVal');
print "Received RecID = $p_RecID\n";
```

Not as proper (two database calls instead of one) but does the job.